# Casting struct pointers in C

Tags: c

when I compiled the following code:

```
AVFrameSideData* avfsd=NULL;
avfsd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
if(avfsd != NULL) {
    int n_mvs = 0;
    if(avfsd->size > 0)
        n_mvs = avfsd->size / sizeof(struct AVMotionVector);
    struct AVMotionVector *mv = (struct AVMotionVector *) (avfsd->data);
    printf("motion vectors of this frame:\n");
    int idx;
    for(idx=0; idx<n_mvs; idx++) {
        printf("mv[%d]:\n", idx);
        if(mv[idx]->source < 0)
            printf("the current macroblock comes from the past\n");
    }
}
```

my compiler complained:

```
video_analysis.c:46:13: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct AVMotionVector’)
   if(mv[idx]->source < 0)
```

Frankly, there's something wrong here:

```
struct AVMotionVector *mv = (struct AVMotionVector *) (avfsd->data);
```

mv is a struct pointer, thereof it's not allowed to access through a two dimensional array manner like *mv[]. However, when I ran it in GDB, I was able to print out things like the following:

```
(gdb) print mv[0]
$2 = {source = -1, w = 16 '\020', h = 16 '\020', src_x = 6, src_y = 10, dst_x = 8, dst_y = 8, flags = 0, motion_x = -5, motion_y = 4, 
  motion_scale = 2}
```

which is exactly what I want to print out...As you can see, mv[0], which can't be accessed from my original code spinet above can now be accessed in GDB mode. How does GDB make this magic happen? If I want to access mv[0] in my program just like in GDB, how should I cast those struct pointers?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Indentation doesn't match with the block scopes. Please [edit] and fix it.

Comment: `avfsd->data` seems to be pointer to array of `struct AVMotionVector`s. If so, then `mv[idx]` is valid way to access those structures. However, in that case  `mv[idx]->source` should probably be replaced with `mv[idx].source`, because you want only one redirection.

Comment: I noticed that there is not a single comment in your code - for your own sanity, fix that bad habit.

Comment: @user694733 does it look better now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if(mv[idx]->source < 0)
```

to

```
if(mv[idx].source < 0)
```

**Explanation**

- `mv` is a *pointer* to `struct AVMotionVector`
- `mv[idx]` is a `struct AVMotionVector` and therefore you need `.`
  instead of `->`.